# C searching for a word in a string

Tags: c, string, file, search

Im trying to write a code that scans a string from the console and tries to find the same word in a .txt file. Then print the word and print if its a positive or a negative word.

The .txt looks like this:

`agree: POZ
 beautiful: POZ
 amazing: POZ
 deny: NEG
 disgusting: NEG
 bad: NEG`

But for some reason the if in the second while doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
int main()
{
char *rijec;
char *vrsta;
char line[200+1];
char konzola[420+1];
char *pch;
char pch1[500];
char rijec1[100];
char vrsta1[50];
//char *ret;

FILE *ulaz;
FILE *izlaz;

ulaz = fopen("Sentiment.txt","r");
izlaz = fopen("RezultatAnalize.txt","w");

if(ulaz == NULL || izlaz == NULL)
    exit(1);

scanf(" %420[^\n]", konzola);
printf("\nKonzola: %s\n", konzola);
pch = strtok (konzola," .!");
//strcpy(pch1, pch);
while (pch != NULL)
{
    //strcpy(pch, pch1);
    printf ("\-  %s  -", pch1);
    strcpy(pch1, pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.!");
    //strcpy(pch1, pch);
}

 while (fgets(line, 200, ulaz) != NULL){
    rijec =(strtok(line,":"));
    vrsta =(strtok(NULL," "));
    strcpy(rijec1, rijec);
    strcpy(vrsta1, vrsta);
    printf("\n%s = %s", rijec, vrsta);
    if(strcmp(rijec1,pch1) == NULL){
        //printf("\nA match has been found");
        printf(" %s......", rijec1);
        if (strcmp(vrsta1,"POZ") == 0)
            printf("Analiza: pozitivna");
        else if (strcmp(vrsta1,"NEG") == 0)
            printf("Analiza: negativna");
    }
 }
```

It just ignores the if statement like its not true. This whole block:

```
if(strcmp(rijec1,pch1) == NULL)
{
    //printf("\nA match has been found");
    printf(" %s......", rijec1);
    if (strcmp(vrsta1,"POZ") == 0)
        printf("Analiza: pozitivna");
    else if (strcmp(vrsta1,"NEG") == 0)
        printf("Analiza: negativna");
}
```

Comment: Which `if` do you mean is "not working" and what do you mean by "not working". Is it not entering the if block, is the application crashing, what is "not working"?

Comment: `vrsta1` include newline. and `pch1` is last word.

Comment: Have you printed out (or stepped through with a debugger) and looked at the values of the strings you are comparing to verify that you are comparing what you think you are comparing?

Comment: I printed it out and went trough it all with a debugger and it does store correct values, and again the debugger just skipped the 'if' block.

Comment: I've pasted the code (without the izlaz file pointer) and it worked fine here when I typed "agree" in console, Got "A match has been found"

Comment: why you are checking equality with `NULL` ? `strcmp` will always return an `INT` value equal, greater or less than 0. As far as i know `NULL` is not always equal to zero.

Comment: hm interesting, if i remove the izlaz file pointer it does print out ''A match has been found'' but it still doesnt print if the word is positive or a negative.

Comment: @Segmentation Thought it would be better to just type an integer, NULL get cast to 0, so it makes no difference in practice. And strcmp won't always return 0, 1 or -1, but 0, >0 or <0. It may vary according to operating systems.

Comment: @MarinKrešić the reason the POZ/NEG if's don't work is because of your strtok. If you look closely vrsta1 always have a line break at the end (\n), so the strcmp will never match. You can easily confirm this by entering 'vrsta1[3] = '\0'; just before the strcmp.

Comment: @PietroPepe I don't know how i missed that , thanks! The only problem now is it doesn't work if the input is a sentence.

Comment: 1) Load as word_table from input file. 2) Sort word_table. 3) check each  word of input by binary search using word_table.

Comment: If the input is a sentence you might want keep extracting the word with strtok and a loop, and do what you are already doing inside this loop. That, though easier, would be way inefficient. You should try to do as @BLUEPIXY suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In …

```
agree: POZ
```

You scan up to the `:` …

```
rijec =(strtok(line,":"));
```

The result is `rijec` pointing to the beginning and a `\0`  (below written as `#`) at the position of the `:`:

```
agree# POZ
^
rijec
```

Then you scan up to :

```
vrsta =(strtok(NULL," "));
```

The result is `vrsta` pointing to that position and that position is `\0` (below written as `#`):

```
agree##POZ
      ^
      vrsta
```

`vrsta`points to an empty string. You have to advance it – or better – continue tokenizing with likely `\n` as delimiter.